# get content from id from list of url's and print in console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to list the footer text from a web application with hundreds of modules/pages. I'm using a script to list all the URL's, but would also like to retrieve the footer text from each of these URL's as this contains the version number of the module.

The code I'm currently using to list the URL's is:

```
urls = document.querySelectorAll('a'); for (url in urls) console.log(urls[url].href);
var ids = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
```

Does anybody know how to get the other part working?
The id of the footer text is either : footerContent or footer-text

Comment: `urls[url].querySelector('#footerContent, #footer-text');` Reads like your `id` is not unique. Should fix that.

Comment: Thanks @Lain, i didn't get a notification of your reply earlier and just tried to add/merge your fix but can't get it to work. Would you mind putting it together for me?

Comment: Could you provide a small example?